# Dissecting using a ruler and compass

Tags: puzzle

The problem is to cut a regular hexagon into parts that can be put together (without overlaps or wasting any parts) to make an equilateral triangle using only a ruler and compass (and scissors).

What is the smallest number of parts that will still let you achieve this?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html shows a picture of a solution that uses 5 parts but I don't know if this can be done with a ruler and compass. I also have no idea how to prove that you can't do it in 4 parts.

**Update.** It seems that a solution by [Harry Lindgren](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Lindgren) (1961) that uses only 5 pieces can indeed be done using ruler and compass.   The question remains how to show it can't be done in 4 pieces. I am also interested to know if Lindgren's solution is unique in some sense.

Comment: @Ryan and others, do you know for a fact that the question of whether the 5=part dissection can be done with ruler and compass, and the question of whether there is a 4-part dissection, are not questions about research level mathematics?

Comment: Similar question posted one day prior to this one at mathstack, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579630/cutting-a-hexagon-to-make-an-equilateral-triangle

Answer (score 3):

In fact the solution shown by Wolfram Mathworld is a constructible five-piece solution, presumably Lindgren's.

Let each side of the hexagon be one unit, and label the hexagon $ABCDEF$ with $A$ at the vertex on the left side and the other vertices ordered clockwise. Then the cut from $A$ to point $G$ on side $BC$ measures half the side of the equilateral triangle, thus $\sqrt6/2$. Point $H$ on side $EF$ is at distance $\sqrt6/2×\sqrt3/2=3\sqrt2/4$ from the cut $AG$, and the cut from $H$ to $I$ on cut $AG$ makes angle $AIH$ which measures $60°$. The length of $HI$ measures $\sqrt6/2$, congruent with $AG$. The remaining cut from $I$ bisects angle $GIH$ and the remaining two cuts (from $D$ and $E$) meet at the center of the hexagon.